# How to connect to MySQL database on port 3308 using laravel framework 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use laravel for the first time. I opned the database.php file located in the config directory and then update the mysql config.

but every time I try to do this command 
php artisan migrate:install

I get this
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machi
  ne actively refused it.

I have to let laravel to connect to a different port somehow.

I have tried the following and none worked.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '10.15.1.5'),
        'port'      => '3308',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb_dev'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

and this

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '10.15.1.5:3308'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb_dev'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

and this

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '10.15.1.5'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3308'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb_dev'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

finally, I tried this

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '10.15.1.5:3308',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb_dev'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

this gives me a different error

```
Access denied for user 'homestead'@'10.xxxxxx' (using password: YES)
```

I am not sure where is the user `homestead` is coming from.

How can I tell laravel to connect to mysql on port 3308?

Comment: Consider testing the connection with PDO like described in [this forum post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/pdo-connection-refused-with-laravel-but-not-with-con-new-pdo) to see if the connection works that way. If it does, try the suggestion from the very last answer there (about specifying the `unix_socket`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. 
the file .env needs to be updated with the correct information

Comment: What if you definitely have the right `DB_PORT` set in `.env` yet Laravel refuses to use that port and sets the `port` configuration to `tcp://172.17.0.2:3306`? Has anyone ever seen such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

I know you figured it out, but of all the attempts you provided, the answer you gave wasn't clear. For those looking in the future, here is what you need:

(This is assuming Laravel 5.1 using a Postgres DB, but should work with alternate versions of Laravel, and different DBs... also, don't mind the alternate/different config settings that my database.php has as opposed to yours, these were for advanced configurations.)

Add a `'port'` section to your `config/database.php`, that looks like follows:

```php
'pgsql' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => env('DB_READ', 'localhost')
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => env('DB_WRITE', 'localhost')
    ],
    'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
    'options'  => [
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => env('DB_PERSISTENT', false)
    ]
]
```

Then in your `.env` you can override the `port` setting as follows:

```
DB_PORT=32769
```