# Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, pdo

In my AWS EC2 Server, I have 2 projects :

1. Laravel Project that connect this RDS DB. I have no pb to connect it
2. Wordpress Project that connect his own DB ( also in RDS ), and also in a plugin, I added a custom connection to my Laravel DB so I can insert data easily.

This code works when I am in localhost, but when I put the real host, it is failing :

```
$capsule->addConnection(array(
 'driver' => 'mysql',
 'host' => 'kendozone.cp90iogazqzc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
 'database' => 'mydb',
 'username' => 'myuser',
 'password' => 'mypas',
 'charset' => 'utf8',
 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
 'prefix' => 'ken_',
 'port'  => '3306'
```

));

This is the error msg:

```
Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in ...
```

What am I missing????

Comment: Your missing the port.

Comment: You are missing the port or either the port is different than the one used in your settings.

Comment: I added the port, but still failing, updated code

Comment: I think you have to change the host from `kendozone.cp90iogazqzc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` to `localhost`

Comment: nop, my db is not local. It is in an external RDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$dbhost = $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'];
$dbport = $_SERVER['RDS_PORT'];
$dbname = $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'];

$dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname}";
$username = $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'];
$password = $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>
```

You are missing the port. [AWS REFERENCE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html)

Comment: isn't it a way to do it with Capsule??? and why is it working in local if port is failing????

Comment: check out this thread @JuliatzindelToro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574722/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-on-port-3308-using-laravel-framework-5-1